# LAN server emulator application

Tags: connection, lan, tcpip

I am looking for a LAN server emulator application capable of doing the following:

- Can connect to it from another application via TCP/IP
- Can send some binary data to my applications

Of course I can write this part but I am looking for something ready. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/)

```
nc -l -p 1234 < binary.dat
```

Then your application can connect to port 1234 on that computer to receive the binary data.

(You could test this with `nc yourservername 1234 > received.dat`)

Please update your question if you have in mind some specific platform, application or network protocol.